# Magento 2 Show Product Custom Option in Custom Page

Tags: magento2, custom-options

> **How to get Product custom option and show into custom page.this is a product custom option.**

[image]

> **Now when add to cart  this product then it's show like this**

[image]

> **When click on add to list data store into table with custom option. I want to show custom option like cart page showing.Problem is showing custom options into custom page.**

[image]

> **Update** **I get this type of array when add to list and I store option into database using jsonencode().**

```
Array
(
    [listid] => 18
    [prdid] => 4
    [product] => 4
    [selected_configurable_option] => 
    [related_product] => 
    [item] => 4
    [form_key] => h6EN0ffZOHD3Ta5K
    [options] => Array
        (
            [3] => 7
            [4] => Custom Val
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 8
                    [1] => 9
                )

            [6] => 10
            [7] => Area Text
            [8] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12
                    [1] => 13
                )

        )

    [options_10_file_action] => save_new
    [qty] => 1
)
```

> **Store into table like this**

```
{"options":{"3":"7","4":"Custom Val","5":["8","9"],"6":"10","7":"Area Text","8":["12","13"]}}
```

***How to do it ?***

Please Help me.

Comment: you are getting cart items on your custom page right?

Comment: No not getting cart item. on product page when i add to list then product added into custom list page. problem is getting and showing custom option like cart page.

Comment: cart cart page they have added the custom options and additional option to cart item. when you getting the same are you ding the same or just getting the product.. because that will not work obviously. because you are not getting any custom or additional options on your custom listing page.

Comment: Please check my updated question. and update me.

Comment: not sure, how to achieve full thing but you can try looking into the `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml` form   line no 46 `<?php $_formatedOptionValue = $block->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>`

Comment: in above array i get custom option with selected value into array, now how to show data with respect to this array which are look like cart page ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114000/discussion-between-rizwan-khan-and-msquare).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step-1 :** Create **registration.php** file at **app/code/Custom/Blog** and add below code.

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Custom_Blog',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step-2 :** Create **module.xml** file at **app/code/Custom/Blog/etc** and add below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_Blog" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step-3 :** Create **routes.xml** file at **app/code/Custom/Blog/etc/frontend** and add below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="blog" id="blog">
            <module name="Custom_Blog"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Step-4 :** Create **Index.php** file at **app/code/Custom/Blog/Controller/Index** and add below code.

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Blog\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('My Custom Page'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**Step-5 :** Create **CustomBlock.php** file at **app/code/Custom/Blog/Block** and add below code.

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Blog\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class CustomBlock extends Template
{
    protected $_productloader;
    protected $_imageBuilder;
    protected $_customOptions;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder $_imageBuilder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option $customOptions,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        $this->_imageBuilder = $_imageBuilder;
        $this->_customOptions = $customOptions;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getLoadProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
    }

    public function getImage($product, $attributes = [])
    {
        $imageId = 'product_base_image';
        return $this->_imageBuilder->setProduct($product)
            ->setImageId($imageId)
            ->setAttributes($attributes)
            ->create();
    }

    public function getCustomOptions($data)
    {
        return $this->_customOptions->getProductOptionCollection($data);
    }

    public function getOptionHtml($prd_data, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option $option)
    {
        $type = $this->getGroupOfOption($option->getType());
        $renderer = $this->getChildBlock($type);
        $renderer->setProduct($prd_data)->setOption($option);
        return $this->getChildHtml($type, false);
    }

    public function getGroupOfOption($type)
    {
        $group = $this->_customOptions->getGroupByType($type);
        return $group == '' ? 'default' : $group;
    }
}
```

**Step-6 :** Create **Customfile.phtml** file at **app/code/Custom/Blog/view/frontend/templates** and add below code.

```
<?php
$id = 4;
// get product collection
$prd_data = $block->getLoadProduct($id);
// get product image
$image = $block->getImage($prd_data);
// get product option data
$prd_custom_op =  $block->getCustomOptions($prd_data);
?>
<div class="product-data-show-main">
    <div class="prd-name"><h2><?php echo $prd_data->getName(); ?></h2></div>
    <div class="product-image-part">
        <?= $image->toHtml() ?>
    </div>
    <div class="product-options-part">
        <?php foreach ($prd_custom_op as $_option): ?>
            <?= $block->getOptionHtml($prd_data, $_option); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Step-7 :** Create **blog_index_index.xml** file at **app/code/Custom/Blog/view/frontend/layout** and add below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
             <block class="Custom\Blog\Block\CustomBlock"
                   name="custom_option_show"
                   template="Custom_Blog::Customfile.phtml"
                   cacheable="false"
                   >
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType"
                       name="product.info.options.default"
                       as="default"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>

                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text"
                       name="product.info.options.text"
                       as="text"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>

                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File"
                       name="product.info.options.file"
                       as="file"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>

                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select"
                       name="product.info.options.select"
                       as="select"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>

                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date"
                       name="product.info.options.date"
                       as="date"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step-7 : Run Magento upgrade command after creating above file

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento c:f
```

Step-8 : Run below URL

```
http://<yourhostname.com>/blog/index/index/
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 0):

First of all, fetch the product id which you want to display a custom page.
then after you get any custom option using the below code you can get the all custom option. pass product id in the second line.
Paste the below code in your custom page phtml file

```
    $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $_product = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(4);
    $customOptions = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($_product);
    foreach ($customOptions as $option) {
        //you can get custom option value here.
        print_r($option->getData());
    }
```

Comment: from above code i can not get drop down labels and radio button values.