# How to show configurable product options in popup in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, modal-popup, configurable-product-options

I have create one popup. In popup get configurable product collection and it working fine. But i have faced one issue. In configurable products collection configurable product options not showing. Like Color and Size. So how to show configurable product options html in popup.

Updated Code :-

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
    [
       ['attribute' => 'sku', 'in' => array($productMains)]
    ]
);
$collection = $productCollection->load();
```

Please Help me.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Please specify your requirement clearly.

Answer (score 2):

> Add to Your phtml file where you want to show Configurable product Swatches.

```
/* For Option show Like Listing */
<?= $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable::class)->setTemplate("Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml")->setProduct($product)->toHtml(); ?>

/* For Option show Like Product View page  */
<?= $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable::class)->setTemplate("Magento_Swatches::product/view/renderer.phtml")->setProduct($product)->toHtml(); ?>
```

**Note:** Here **$product** is Configurable product object comes from **Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory**. after add code please run cache clean command **php bin/magento c:c**

Please check magento **Magento_Swatches** module in Vendor Folder path **root/vendor/magento/module-swatches**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
    [
       ['attribute' => 'sku', 'in' => array($productMains)]
    ]
);
$collection = $productCollection->load();

foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($value->getId());
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable::class)->setTemplate("Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml")->setProduct($product)->toHtml();
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks it is working but options value not showing https://prnt.sc/1ghcs9j

Comment: Please set product dtata by using Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory class.

Comment: Also share your code.

Comment: I have updated my question and i have used **ResourceModel** class.

Comment: please check and update me. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94851/magento2-how-to-load-product-by-id for load product

Comment: For show custom Options check this url https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/331816/82670

Comment: i have try but options value not showing.

Comment: Please Download this module and check it https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1G_iVWbSMpQaQbqVR_E4vORsv706CYMv7?usp=sharing  YourHost/blog/index/index is URL And update me.

Comment: @MohitPatel Have You checked?  The above module is working. Follow module code it helps you.

Comment: Your module working fine but my phtml file load in controller. So your module blog_index_index.xml file code how to load?

Comment: i have use this class *\Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127971/discussion-between-mohit-patel-and-msquare).

Comment: above module working only Swatches options.

Comment: Hello @Msquare Please help in this issue

Comment: @MohitPatel Please share your code. So I can understand. In my Module custom Options and Swatches are showing well.

Answer (score 1):

You should extend your custom block to \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct like below and load your custom collection as per you want in block

```
<?php
namespace PackageName\HomeContent\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime;

class NewProductCollection extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    protected $_catalogProductVisibility;

    protected $_date;
    
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        DateTime $dateTime,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
        $this->_date                     = $dateTime;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $postDataHelper, $layerResolver,
            $categoryRepository, $urlHelper, $data);
    }

    public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        $visibleProducts = $this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds();
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->setVisibility($visibleProducts);
        $collection = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable')->setPageSize(10);
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Now in your custom phtml file copy content from vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

Please check.

Cheers!

Comment: i have already tried this solution but my question is how to get configurable products collection with its options.like Color and Size.

Comment: In list page of your website, color and size options are showing or not? Like this - https://prnt.sc/1g4izux

Comment: You have asked in question like you have already got configurable products collection and you are just facing issue with color and size option

Comment: Please edit your question.

Comment: Please copy  content from vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml from your custom phtml file. I have edited answer and shown you that how to get configurable products collection. Your custom block needs to extend with \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct. It will display configurable product options as well.